# Slickgrid Sort implementation does not work

Tags: jquery, angularjs, sorting, slickgrid

Sort implementation does not work. For columns where I have set sortable: true, on click of the header I see that the subscribe function is being called but nothing happens. Both dataRow1 and dataRow2 have the correct information and the sign returns the value it is supposed to return but the grid render does not work. Any help will be appreciated.

```
var data = getDataForGrid(); 

var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
    dataView.beginUpdate();
    dataView.setItems(data, 'employeeID');
    dataView.endUpdate();

var grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, getColumnHeadersForGrid(), getOptions());

    grid.onSort.subscribe(function(e,args){
    var cols = args.sortCol;
    dataView.sort(function (dataRow1, dataRow2) {
        var field = cols[i].sortCol.field;
        var value1 = null;
        var value2 = null;

        if(dataRow1 !=null){
            value1 = dataRow1[sortedColumns.field];
        }

        if(dataRow2 !=null){
            value2 = dataRow2[sortedColumns.field];
        }
        var sign = cols[i].sortAsc ? 1: -1;
        var result = (value1 ==value2 ? 0 : (value1 > value2 ? 1: -1)) * sign;

        if(result != 0) {
            return result;
        }
        return 0;

    });
    grid.invalidate();
    grid.render();
}        


function getDataForGrid(){
    var data = [];
    //Have logic to get the data
    return data;
}

function getColumnHeadersForGrid(){
    var columns = [];
    columns.push({id:"employeeID", name:"Employee ID", field:"employeeID", sortable: true, width: 200});
    columns.push({id:"title", name:"Title", field:"title", sortable: true, width: 200});
        columns.push({id:"duration", name:"Duration", field:"duration", sortable: true, width:150});
        columns.push({id:"%", name:"% Complete", field:"percentComplete", sortable: true, width: 200});

    return columns;

}
function
```

Comment: It's an angularjs library? You pretend to use with angularjs?

Comment: Yeah. This is angularjs

Answer (score 0):

```
var cols = args.sortCol;
```

this is not an array - this is one of your columns defined in `getColumnHeadersForGrid()`

`sortedColumns` is at all not defined in your snippet

try this:

```
grid.onSort.subscribe(function(e,args){
    var field = args.sortCol.field;
    var sign = args.sortAsc ? 1: -1;

    dataView.sort(function (dataRow1, dataRow2) {
        value1 = dataRow1[field];
        value2 = dataRow2[field];

        var result = (value1 ==value2 ? 0 : (value1 > value2 ? 1: -1)) * sign;

        return result;

    });
});
```